# how to get which option did I click when I'm using JOptionPane.showOptionDialog?Why do I get incomporable types error

Tags: java, joptionpane

I wanna say excuse me first for my lack english. I am not a native speaker.

So, I am creating a rock scissor paper game with GUI in Java.

The algorithm is very simple. I will get a showOptionDialog with three buttons. (rock, scissor, paper) When I click one of the three buttons, Java will compare my choice and computer's choice. Computer will choose random number between 1~3

I am almost finished with my GUI but I have some problem with showOptionDialog

```
private String[]a = {"Rock","Paper","Scissor"};
private int userChoice;
/* some codes 
 */
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if(e.getSource()==play){
        userChoice = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,"Rock Paper Scissor","Choose",JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null,a,a[1]);
        if(userChoice==a[0] )
    }
}
```

I tried something like this but as you know java shows me an incomporable types int and String. Any good idea how should I do?

Comment: What is the exact error message which you get?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice asI mentioned, before compiling, Java shows an incomporable types error. After compiling I don't know now. I am not finished with my code and I cannot compile now.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice The problem is I know why java shows an incomporable types but I have no idea how should I do in other way

Comment: Please edit your question to show the **exact** error message **word for word**. By summarizing, you are leaving out important information that will be helpful for future readers to understand what the problem is.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice ok ok thanks I will do that

Answer (score 1):

As you know, [JOptionPane.showOptionDialog()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showOptionDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object)) returns an `int`, not a `String`. So you cannot compare `userChoice` to one of the `String` elements of `a`. Instead, use `userChoice` as the index to get the choice:

```
if (userChoice != JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION) {
    String choice = a[userChoice];
    // Do something with choice
}
```

To determine the results of the game, you can just as easily use `userChoice` directly, rather than the `String` representation. For example, instead of "rock beats scissors" think of it as "0 beats 1".

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am really sleepy now so I cannot code but I will test your advice later. Thanks